# how does mincore work with shared tmpfs files

Tags: c, linux, memory, tmpfs

According to the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mincore.2.html),

> mincore() returns a vector that indicates whether pages of the
> calling process's virtual memory are resident in core (RAM), and
> so will not cause a disk access (page fault) if referenced.

But, I'm unclear as to the exact meaning of this -- specifically does RAM refer to the target process's virtual memory, or any processes mapped memory?

Say you have a tmpfs file (tmpfs.file) that is shared between two process's -- process A and process B.   Process A maps tmpfs.file, but only accesses page 0.  Now process B accesses page 2.  And no one accesses page 1.   What would be the expected output of mincore as run by process A -- would it be [1,0,0], or [1,0,1]?   Technically, page2 exists in process B's RAM, or on the system's RAM, but process A might not have a virtual memory mapping to it, so I'm not sure if this counts...   (Tests show it does appear, but I'd like to be sure this is correct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RAM means physical memory. RAM belongs to the ayarwm, there's no such thing as process A's RAM and process B's RAM.

When the processes map the file, they each have 3 pages of virtual memory allocated to the mapping (I'm assuming the file size is 3 pages).

When A accesses page 0, that page is fetched into RAM. At that time, `mincore()` should return `[1, 0, 0]` when run by either process.

When B accesses page 2, that page is fetched into RAM. Assuming nothing causes page 0 to be ejected, `mincore()` will then return `[1, 0, 1]` in either process.

It doesn't matter whether the process that calls `mincore()` has accessed a particular page. If some other process has accessed the page, it will be loaded into RAM, and this process won't get a page fault when trying to access it.

Things can get weird when using virtual filesystems like `tmpfs`, since the filesystem itself can be stored in RAM -- there's nothing to read in from disk.